# Confusing exercise question about modal verbs

Tags: grammar

I found this question in an exercise on modal verbs.

> Find the mistake:
>
> > Yesterday; I think he travelled last week.

Where is the mistake and what does (yesterday & last week) refer to?

Comment: What is your thinking on it?  I agree that it's confusing, but which part is confusing to you?

Comment: I don't even know its meaning (yeterday; and last week together in the same sentence are confusing me)

Comment: Without context the sentence is basically nonsense as written. The portion after the semicolon stands on its own, but the "Yesterday;" just makes no sense.  Were the instructions any more involved than "Find the mistake:"?

Comment: Moreover, there is no modal verb in this quotation.

Comment: The exercise is poorly constructed, I think. "Find the mistake" is more like "Guess what this sentence is trying to say!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were constructing the sentence today, yet referring to yesterday's knowledge, the structure might be

> Yesterday; I thought he travelled next week.

Though that in itself implies new knowledge was acquired today, adding a

> ... however, today I discovered differently; he will travel tomorrow.

I cannot think of an instance where 'yesterday' can logically be followed by 'think' *[please feel free to correct me]* unless it was "Yesterday, at least I think it was yesterday, if not the day before.." etc

I'd need more context on the original quote, I think.... (or I think I thought I think...)